# What's the meaning of "default-proof" in a financial context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

> For decades, general obligation bonds have been marketed as virtually
>   **default-proof**, and a major restructuring of them now by Puerto Rico would raise unwelcome questions about the credibility of the
>    time-honored “full faith and credit” pledge that stands behind such
>   bonds. Puerto Rico is not proposing to walk away from its bonds
>    completely, but to pay its investors less.

The above paragraph which has been excerpted from [nytimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/09/10/business/dealbook/puerto-rico-lays-out-5-year-plan-for-restructuring-its-debts.html?_r=0). What's the meaning of **default-proof** in the context?

Comment: I'm really glad you found my answer helpful, but you may want to wait a little while before accepting an answer. This post explains why http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default in this sense means to not make required payments on a loan. Default-proof means that there is virtually no risk that the bond won't be paid when the time comes.

It's similar to [fireproof](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fireproof) or [childproof](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/childproof).

As @TRomano pointed out in the comments "default-proof" is a sort of [doublespeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak). A child-proof cap can withstand a young child's attempts to open it, but a bond can not withstand the entity that issued the bond refusing to pay what was promised. Bonds only have value if the money that was loaned is repaid, so a better phrase than "virtually default-proof" might be "virtually risk-free" or "very low risk".

The opposite of the "default-proof" bonds mentioned in the article are [junk bonds](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/j/junkbond.asp). These bonds have a very high risk that they won't be paid back, but they also have a higher yield to make them attractive to investors. They are also called non-investment grade bonds because they are more like gambling than investing.

Comment: +1.  Shatter-proof, child-proof , fire-proof, fool-proof. They all imply "able to withstand". But a default-proof bond is not able to withstand defaulting. The word is a walking lie :)

Comment: There are other kinds of risk besides credit risk.  For example, interest rate risk, pre-payment risk, inflation risk, confiscation risk, and risk of changes in the tax code.  Even if there is "very low risk" of default, a bond can still be quite risky -- especially when interest rates are volatile.

Comment: @Jasper Naturally you're correct - I probably should have put a disclaimer in small print lol. Do you have a better suggestion to substitute for default-proof? I was thinking low-risk because in the context (an article in the general press) it would be close enough. Most of the population thinks of default when they think of bond risks and it doesn't cross their mind that if the yield is too low their bonds could be worth less than nothing if the term is too long.